# Craft 3: how can I auto-redirect to a site version using the user IP?

Tags: localization, craft3, redirect, cookies

I have set up multi-sites using several locales:

```
— International Website
    — English
— Local Website
    — French
    — Dutch
    — etc.
```

If the user has a French or Dutch IP, it should be auto-redirect to the Local Website version. Otherwise, it should be redirected to International Website.

I found this plugin, that probably could make this works: https://github.com/lukeyouell/craft3-geocookie. I guess I would need to check the cookie inside my base.twig layout before to finally `{% redirect %}` to the matching version?

But I was wondering if there were (better) other ways to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Country Redirect](https://superbig.co/plugins/country-redirect) will let you do that without any latency from external services, with the soon-to-be-released Craft 3 version (I'll update the answer once its out).

Comment: Thank you! When is scheduled the release of the your Craft 3 plugin?

Comment: I'll try to have it out within the next couple weeks.